# npm version is lower than what I installed (ubuntu 22.04) (first apt and then binary install)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Version seems to be different from what is installed.

I was getting warnings on npm install
I installed the binary into my home/development dir, but it was not working with sudo.  So I installed with apt.  (note:  I did not really install, I extracted and put path in /etc/environment)

That was not working so I downloaded the binary for linux64 again and installed in usr/local/bin and I left the name of the version of the folder.

```
$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/node-v16.15.0-linux-x64/bin/npm


$ npm -v
8.5.5
$ node -v
v12.22.9
```

When I do npm install I get this error

```
pm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'electron-builder@22.14.13',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'app-builder-lib@22.14.13',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

The official website says I need to install npm with npm. Not sure what that means.  Other websites say extracting and putting the path is enough.  Sudo does not seem to work unless i do an apt install.  Perhaps there is something left over with the previous apt install that shows the wrong version?

It is not easy to get electron-builder to install.  I have had many problems in the past.  now I installed ubuntu 22.04 and I'm rebuilding my dev system with trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation for a comment so here:

This is not exactly an npm Problem
It seems your Version of NodeJS is too low for the requiered Packages installed.
Try update your nodejs version
the latest npm version is 8.9 you can update npm if you wanted with this command

```sh
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: I did not fully remove npm and nodejs from apt correctly.  Once I did that and installed the binary (or simply put in the path, it worked.  Furthermore, I had to change rights to that path for using with global installs instead of using sudo (which did not work).  Now all is well.